# Relation between sum and product of two numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be two non-negative numbers and let $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$ be a given constant. Is there a relation (like inequalities) between $t_1$ and $t_2$ defined as 
\begin{align}
t_1 &= \lambda a + (1-\lambda) b \\
t_2 &= a^{\lambda}b^{1-\lambda}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write AM-GM as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{na+mb}{n+m} \geq \sqrt[n+m]{a^nb^m}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b \geq a^{\lambda}b^{1- \lambda }.
\end{eqnarray*}